# Converting long int to wxString

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

In wxWiki i found this page http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Converting_everything_to_and_from_wxString. It describes how to convert *int* to *wxString*, but doesn't describe how to convert *long int* into *wxString*.

After compilation application works, but compiler throws this warning twice (I convert long int to wxString twice):

> [Warning] int format, long int arg (arg 3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conversion from **long** to **wxString**:

```
long l;
...
wxString strLong = wxString::Format(wxT("%ld"), l);
```

Conversion from **long long**:

```
wxLongLong ll;
... 
wxString strLongLong = ll.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Reference to [wxString::Format](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxstring.html#wxstringformat) says that it uses `Printf` function that is like [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/), that has `l` modifiter for `long int`, so it seems you should use `%li` format